# supertest and multiple execution of similar routes

Tags: node.js, express, sinon, supertest

I'm trying to test two routes that are pretty much the same except that one of them is more specific as the latest url segment is a hardcoded value (edit) while the other has a parameter (:slug).

The issue I'm experiencing is that when the request is executed it will call both routes (edit, show) causing my mock never() expectation never pass :(

Am I doing something wrong? I dont't get why both routes are executing if one of them is more specific...

This is the test:

```
var request = require('supertest')
    , express = require('express')


describe('routes', function() {
    it('should call only edit', function(done) {
        var usersController = require('./users-controller');
        var sandbox = require('sinon').sandbox.create();
        var mockController = sandbox.mock(usersController);

        mockController.expects('edit').yields(null).once();
        mockController.expects('show').never();

        var app = express();

        app.get('/users/:id/edit', usersController.edit);
        app.get('/users/:id/:slug', usersController.show);

        request(app)
          .get('/users/123/edit')
          .end(function(err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
            mockController.verify();
            done();
          });
    });
});
```

and here is the **users-controlle.js** I'm mocking above:

```
exports.edit = function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('edit');
}

exports.show = function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's to be expected.

Express will execute all routes which match a given URL in the order they were registered with the `app` object. To bypass any later callbacks you can use `next('route')`. See the section on [application routing in the express API guide](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your 'show' in callback in function called then 'edit' done